# Restrict action only within a spefific DIV with a ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the Fiddle you can see my Problem. How do i restict the action within a spefic class. When hohvering the thumbnail-image only the image within parent div should be appear. In my case the image in the other div appears also.

There seems to be a problem with the JSFiddle Snippet in Stackoverflow. So here is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/te6x9ohv/11/

```js
$('.ImageAttributeList').mouseenter(function () {
  $('div.previewImages')
  .hide()
  .after('<div class="thumbnailPreview">' +
         '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">' +
         '</div>');
});

$('.ImageAttributeList').mouseleave(function () {
  $('div.previewImages').show();
  $('div.thumbnailPreview').remove();
});
```

```css
.item { float: left; padding: 0 20px; width: 300px }
.itemMain { height: 302px; }
.previewImages, .thumbnailPreview  { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }
.previewImages img, .thumbnailPreview img { border: 1px solid #DDD; width: 300px; }
.imgatt { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }
.imgatt img { max-width: 50px; }
.ImageAttributeList { margin: 4px; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid #DDD }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>
<center>
<h3>item-ID1</h3>
</center>
<div class="item item-ID1">
<div class="itemMain">
<div class="previewImages">
    <img src="https://magento.fashionette.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/725x725/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/u/g/ugg-92665-02.jpg">
<div class="thumbnailPreview">
</div>
</div>

<div class="imgatt">
    <img class="ImageAttributeList" src="https://picture1.cyberport.de/mall/shopde/pic/zbild3/zbild3-859346A409-1K3_1500.JPG">
    <img class="ImageAttributeList" src="https://picture1.cyberport.de/mall/shopde/pic/zbild5/zbild5-859346A409-1K3_1500.JPG">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<center><h3>item-ID2</h3></center>
<div class="item item-ID2">
<div class="itemMain">
<div class="previewImages">
    <img src="https://magento.fashionette.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/725x725/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/u/g/ugg-92551-02.jpg">
<div class="thumbnailPreview">
</div>
</div>

<div class="imgatt">
    <img class="ImageAttributeList" src="https://picture1.cyberport.de/mall/shopde/pic/zbild3/zbild3-859346A409-1K3_1500.JPG">
    <img class="ImageAttributeList" src="https://picture1.cyberport.de/mall/shopde/pic/zbild5/zbild5-859346A409-1K3_1500.JPG">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the JQuery `:eq` psuedo selector to select a number occurence of a certain selector.  See below:

```
$('.ImageAttributeList:eq(2)').mouseenter(function () {
  $('div.previewImages:eq(0)')
  .hide()
  .after('<div class="thumbnailPreview">' +
         '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">' +
         '</div>');
});

$('.ImageAttributeList:eq(3)').mouseenter(function () {
  $('div.previewImages:eq(1)')
  .hide()
  .after('<div class="thumbnailPreview">' +
         '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">' +
         '</div>');
});
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/te6x9ohv/22/)

Comment: Then I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. Can you be a littler clearer on the behavior you want?

Comment: Sorry my english is not the best :-) i want that the image only appers in one "item". In my case the image appers in both items

Comment: No problem. Did you look at the fiddle i created in my answer? It has the thumbnail appearing in the first image (I think that's what you want). Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. And yes, the first image changes correctly when i hover one of the thumbnails below. But if i hover one of the thumbnails at the second item, the image appers also on the first item: https://jsfiddle.net/te6x9ohv/18/

Comment: I think i understand now.

Comment: I just need a script which considers the classes "item-ID1", "Item-ID2" and so on.

Comment: Does not seem to work :-( : https://jsfiddle.net/te6x9ohv/21/                         is there no way to include the "item-ID..." in the script. Because very item has a spefic ID and so you could specify the action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164941/discussion-between-jonathan-chaplin-and-hippolas-cage).

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your event with

```
$('.ImageAttributeList').mouseenter(function () {
  $(this).closest(".itemMain").find(".previewImages")
  .hide()
  .after('<div class="thumbnailPreview">' +
         '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">' +
         '</div>');
});
```